# load image from char buffer

Tags: qt, qt4

I need to construct an image with unsigned char data I receive from a compressed/decompressed image. For this, I just wrote a simple program to test buffer loading from image and vice versa. As I run the code, I cannot setpixmap the image to the background.

```
void MainWindow::LoadImage()
{
    //======== Load buffer from image
    unsigned char buffer[_width*_height*COLOR_COMPONENTS]; //1024 * 768 * 3
    QImage image;
    image.load("://image.jpg", "JPEG");
    memcpy(buffer, image.bits(), _width*_height*COLOR_COMPONENTS);

    //========= Load image from buffer
    QImage img;
    img.loadFromData((const char*)buffer);
    QPixmap px = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    ui->label->setPixmap(px);
}
```

UPDATED:
I changed the code to this, however, I get segmentation fault with memcpy.

> ```
> unsigned char buffer[400*300*3];
> ```

```
QImage image(_width, _height, QImage::Format_RGB32);

image.load("://image.jpg", "JPEG");

memcpy(buffer, image.bits(), 400*300*3);



QImage img(400, 300, QImage::Format_RGB32);

img.loadFromData((const uchar*)buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char), "JPG");

QPixmap px = QPixmap::fromImage(img);

ui->label->setPixmap(px);
```

Comment: `loadFromData` expects a proper image format (PNG, JPG...) and not raw data. Create an image with the same format and memcpy the buffer over its `bits()`. Note also that your calculations might be incorrect: QImage scanlines should always be 32-bit aligned (check the docs/source).

Answer (score 4):

[loadFromData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#loadFromData) requires the data to be in a certain format (PNG, JPG...), the plain array is not a valid one

however doing

```
QImage img(buffer,_width, _height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

will return a image of the correct size and format but will only be valid for as long as buffer is alive

Comment: Ratchet, thank you for your hint. But honestly, i still do not get the image. i updated the code above.

Comment: because in you updated code buffer is still raw pixel data and you try to parse it like a jpeg